# include a view file that it's name is in a variable into an EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I use this method to include an `ejs` file in my template:

```
<% include header %>
```

But if `header` is a variable, I get some errors. How i can include a file that it's name is in a variable into an `ejs` template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't:

https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/93

The issue was opened in 2013 and never resolved.

However, in version 2 you call `include` [as a plain function](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes):

```
<%- include(header) %>
```